# check object data match my id value then load inner object

Tags: javascript

```
var _id = "displayImage1"

my object 
var obj = {
    displayImage1: {
        object: "style";
    },
     displayImage2: {
        object: "style";
    },
     displayImage3: {
        object: "style";
    }
}
```

How do I loop through my object and check if the name are same as the _id then load the inner object?

1. I wanted to check if the `obj` object match my _id name with loop.
2. After I check it had the same name then load the inner object style.

Here is what I tried but didn't get anything.

```
for (var i in obj) {
  if(obj[i] === _id){
    console.log(obj[i]['object']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Access the property directly, with `json[_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the **value** at key `i` is equal to the id you are looking for. Instead you want to check if the **key** itself is equal, right?

```
  if (i === _id) {
```

But you don't need to loop at all. The whole point of objects is that you can retrieve their values by simply giving the key:

```
obj[_id]
```

And then pick a value from with that by giving its key:

```
obj[_id].object
```

By the way, nothing about this problem as anything to do with "JSON". JSON is a serialization form for exchanging information. The objects you are dealing with are plain old JavaScript objects.

Answer (score -1):

### Edited

You can check if the key exists like so, and then apply the value as a style:

```
if (json[_id]) {
    element.style = json[_id].object;
} else {//does not exist}
```

Answer (score -1):

Compare the **_id** with json **attribute**, don't compare the hole object.

Try this code.

```js
var _id = "displayImage1";
//my object 
var json = {
  displayImage1: {
    object: "style"
  },
  displayImage2: {
    object: "style"
  },
  displayImage3: {
    object: "style"
  }
}
for (var i in json) {
  if (i === _id) {
    console.log(json[i]['object']);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Or `console.log(json[_id].object)`?